# css position property and dynamic height

Tags: css, position

I want to implement 3 DIVs inside a container, just like table rows

> **top** {height = 100px} / **middle** {height = dynamic} / **bottom** {height = 100px}

Now the question is what is the best approach to have the middle div's height dynamic and keep the structure correct.

- Here's what I've done so far: http://jsfiddle.net/pvPSD/4/

HTML

```
<div id="notification">
<div id="n-top">
    top
</div>
<div id="n-middle">
    middle<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />middle
</div>
<div id="n-bottom">
    bottom
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#notification {
    position:absolute;
    left:10px;
    top:10px;
    width:175px;
    background: yellow;
}

#n-top {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    width:175px;
    height:50px;
    background: blue;
}

#n-middle {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:14px;
    width:175px;
    background: red;
}

#n-bottom {
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    width:175px;
    height:50px;
    background: green;
}
```

Comment: I'm sort of confused about what you're trying to do. Could you explain in more detail or give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This here worked for me

```
#notification {
    position:absolute;
    left:10px;
    top:10px;
    width:175px;
    background: yellow;
}

#n-top {
    position:relative;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    width:175px;
    height:50px;
    background: blue;
}

#n-middle {
    position:relative;
    left:0px;
    width:175px;
    background: red;
}

#n-bottom {
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    width:175px;
    height:50px;
    background: green;
}
```

**Remember** that absolute postitionning removes the element from then normal flow of the page.  The way you had it had all the elements placed in absolute postionning.  Therefore, they didn't *hold* their position within the page.  Hence, the following elements were bascially looking to be placed at the top.  Having the position relative, the location of the element is preserved on the page, and the next one is looking to be place after.

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Just put top and bottom margin  to your middle section, add a wrapper with position:relative and top section and bottom section inside the wrapper, with position:absolute and with height equals your margin.

Answer (score 0):

If the top and bottom `<div>`s are a static height, then you can set the middle `<div>` to position 0,0 with height 100% and a margin at the top to match the height of the top `<div>` and a margin at the bottom to match the height of the bottom `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems to me (I may have understood what you want wrong.) that getting rid of the positioning elements (absolute, top, left, bottom)for the inner div's from your css keeps it looking correct regardless of how big the middle div is. Is there some other reason why you need absolute positioning on those inner elements?

Comment: Thank you and the answer is yes, I'm using slicing feature of adobe photoshop for a long time and as you know, this is the way ps deals with all the divs (as far as I know)